# show list of top scorers in a table of Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with 3 columns named gameresults: `game_id`,`user_id`,`status`

i put every time two players play a game two rows in the table

`game_id = 1, user_id = 12, status = 1`

`game_id = 1, user_id = 13, status = -1`

status will get only 3 value (**1** for wins, **-1** for lose, **0** for draw)

now I want to show a list of top players who has wins more games with some info of how many games played.
how can i query this out?

and one other thing that i want is to show the current user(example user_id 2) rank in current game(game_id 1)

[image: screenshot of table colums]

Comment: Use `SUM(status)`, `GROUP BY user_id`, and `ORDER BY`. Very basic SQL stuff.

Comment: @Barmar I don't want to sum status. for example a user played 10 times and wins 5 loose 3 and draw 2 must be on top of a player that plays 7 times and wins 4 loose 1 draw 2 times.

Comment: Calculate percentage wins per total games played

Comment: `SUM(status = 1)` will count the wins.

Comment: `SUM(status = 1) / COUNT(*)` will calculate the win fraction.

Comment: @AliQorbani - you could multiply the `SUM(status)` by `COUNT(*)` that would give your first player *20 "points"* and your second *14* - the multiplier will weight the scores by the number of games played.